# Load a modal window from a bookmarklet (like the Amazon wishlist bookmarklet)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a bookmarklet to load an html page which all works great, but, doesn't look so hot due to browsers generally being ugly around the outside!

Is there a way to load the page completely frameless? Like a jquery modal version of it which I don't think is possible from within the page, overlaying itself so to speak.

Is there a way to maybe throw the page out in document.write commands and put a js version of it out there instead? Or some other way?

Amazon Example:

Create a bookmarklet using the following to code to get a clearer example of what I mean - doesn't matter if you don't have an account you'll see the effect.

```
javascript:(function(){var%20w=window,l=w.location,d=w.document,s=d.createElement('script'),e=encodeURIComponent,o='object',n='AUWLBookenGB',u='https://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/add',r='readyState',T=setTimeout,a='setAttribute',g=function(){d[r]&&d[r]!='complete'?T(g,200):!w[n]?(s[a]('charset','UTF-8'),s[a]('src',u+'.js?loc='+e(l)+'&b='+n),d.body.appendChild(s),f()):f()},f=function(){!w[n]?T(f,200):w[n].showPopover()};typeof%20s!=o?l.href=u+'?u='+e(l)+'&t='+e(d.title):g()}())
```

Comment: Are you asking for a way to display a browser window without any window chrome? I'm afraid that might be beyond anything you can do with javascript.

Comment: @Radu yes, exactly that, amended question with example

Comment: Thanks.... [now this page is on my wish list :-P](http://www.amazon.co.uk/registry/wishlist/2EU2F4LZYVZI7)

Comment: Updated @Neal, hope that helps you understand it (originally thought you were referring to something else)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If all you want is to show some html that you have on another page, you can do something like this:

```
var modal = document.createElement('iframe');
modal.setAttribute('src', 'http://codinghorror.com');
modal.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no'); // no scroll bars on the iframe please
modal.className = 'modal';
document.body.appendChild(modal);
```

With some basic styles:

```
.modal {
    border:0;            
    height:200px;
    position:fixed;
    right:20px;
    top:20px;
    width:200px;
    z-index:101;   
}​
```

Of course, you should load these styles from a remote host:

```
var c = document.createElement('link');
c.type = 'text/css';
c.rel = 'stylesheet';
c.href = '//example.com/main.css';
document.body.appendChild(c);
```

So your bookmarklet looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/radu/mTKHQ/. This is with the css hosted locally since I didn't bother uploading it anywhere. Now, this is very barebones and there is obviously a lot more you can do. First of all, you can write your own DOM instead of using an iFrame. You can add a close button, various events, etc. At that point, it would make sense to do what amazon did and use a script/stylesheet loader to load files from a remote host, like so:

```
(function (d) {
    var s = d.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = '//example.com/main.js';
    d.body.appendChild(s);
    var c = d.createElement('link');
    c.type = 'text/css';
    c.rel = 'stylesheet';
    c.href = '//example.com/main.css';
    d.body.appendChild(c);
}(document));
```

Prepend this with `javascript:`, and you've got your new bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(d){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='//example.com/main.js';d.body.appendChild(s);var c=d.createElement('link');c.type='text/css';c.rel='stylesheet';c.href='//example.com/main.css';d.body.appendChild(c);}(document));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest, most light-weight solution would be to use `window.open`.

Something like the following will display a 600x250 window in the middle of the screen. Only the titlebar will show, which can show the title of the window.

Paste this in your browser's URL field to try it out:

```
javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20d=document;window.open('http://stackoverflow.com','_blank','width=600,height=250,left='+(screen.width/2-300)+',top='+(screen.height/2-125))%7D)();
```

Comment: This works very well as a bookmarklet most of the time. Any idea why it doesn't open the window e.g. on https://github.com ? I'm using FF 20.0.1 on Win7.

Comment: Firefox implements the content security policy of github in a way that breaks bookmarklets. It seems to be a long standing bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:(function()%20{if(typeof%20jQuery=='undefined'){var%20jqit=document.createElement('script');jqit.type='text/javascript';jqit.src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqit);}%20_my_script=document.createElement('script');_my_script.type='text/javascript';_my_script.src='http://font-friend.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/font-friend.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_my_script);})();
```

That is the code for the "font-friend" bookmarklet, which creates a popup on a given site. You could just alter the code references to your individual needs, but should give a starting point.

here is the link to it http://somadesign.ca/projects/fontfriend/

Answer (score -1):

Upon looking at it more, and inspecting the bookmarklet that appears, here is the overall code structure:

```
    javascript: (function() { 
       var w = window, 
       l = w.location, 
       d = w.document, 
       s = d.createElement('script'), 
       e = encodeURIComponent, 
       x = 'undefined', 
       u = 'http://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/add'; 
       if (typeof s != 'object') l.href = u + '?u=' + e(l) + '&t=' + e(d.title); 
       function g() { 
          if (d.readyState && d.readyState != 'complete') { 
             setTimeout(g, 200); 
          } else { 
             // testing if AUWLBook is undefined (AUWL is their global object for it)
             // If it is, they add the <script> tag for their JS (variable u)
             if (typeof AUWLBook == x) s.setAttribute('src', u + '.js?loc=' + e(l)), 
             d.body.appendChild(s); 
             function f() { 
                // they keep looping through until the Object is finally created
                // Then they call the showPopover function which initializes everything
                // Builds all the HTML (with JS, etc)
                (typeof AUWLBook == x) ? setTimeout(f, 200) : AUWLBook.showPopover(); 
             } 
             f(); 
          } 
       } 
       g(); 
    }())
```

As you can see an anonymous function is being created, and the jist of what is happening here is that they are creating a script element **s = d.createElement('script')**, into your current document which then loads the rest of the bookmarklet.

```
// since their global object will be undefined at first they create it
if (typeof AUWLBook == x) s.setAttribute('src', u + '.js?loc=' + e(l)), 
   d.body.appendChild(s);
```

As for the string building for the href... it looks like `l.href = u + '?u=' + e(l) + '&t=' + e(d.title);` is for their internal reference so they know what page/etc you came from, i'm assuming they are building what the Wish list item is from the Title of the page (that's what it looks like at least).

You can see their entire JS code here, they have a whole lot going on:
[Amazong Bookmarklet JS Link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/add.js?loc=http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/&b=AUWLBookenGB)

But as you can see they build the entire popup & the DOMelements straight from Javascript:

```
  // (part of the AUWLBook object)
  showPopover : function(args){
  // etc etc...

  // open in window if it can't create a popover
  if (!this.canDisplayPopover()) {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/add' + '?u=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location) + '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title);
    return;
  }

  // Then comes just an insane amount of lines of creating all the elements
  floater = shmCreateElement('table', { width: bookmarkletWidth, border: '0', id: 'auwlPopover' }, {position: 'absolute', zIndex: '999999999', width: bookmarkletWidth, tableLayout: 'auto', lineHeight: '100%', borderCollapse: 'collapse'});
```

shmCreateElement being their internal html creation function (i'd def suggest copying it)

```
     function shmCreateElement(tagName, props, styles, children) { ... }
```

So I guess basically you need to have whatever you want to appear completely coming from JS, have it injected into the current pages document DOM, and there you go.

Comment: My OP has nothing to do with fullscreen. I basically want to load a popup (for want of a better word) without any chrome on the browser.

Comment: Ahh sorry... Have you tried some sort of jQuery UI dialogbox ?

Comment: No probs, can't do that, wish i could would be easy then - its a pop up window, it is spawned from a bookmarklet

Comment: What about `window.open(url, '_blank', 'toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=300,height=400,resizable=no,scrollbars=no');` ?

Comment: Please read the original post and try the code I added there - it clearly can be done, I simply don't know how.

Comment: Updated some more info for ya, I didn't understand what it was at first, but I see now